# Create an event listener page or link on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, event-listener

How to create an event listener page or link on wordpress where it listen from a push notification. Im new to wordpress and I don't have any idea on where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing recently. And the following page pointed me in the right direction:

http://docs.appthemes.com/tutorials/creating-a-wordpress-listener/

Pretty much you create and execute a function that checks the request and intercepts it based on some check.

In the example they are checking a querystring var (but you can essentially check anything). The author suggests implementing more checks since the endpoint could easily be abused (maybe checking who is making the request or that the request contains some secret value.)

Anyway, the link pointed me in the right direction so I thought I'd pass it on.